# Airflow 2.0 SQL Server connector

Tags: sql-server, docker-compose, airflow, pyodbc, pymssql

I want to use the airflow 2.01 docker-compose file from apaches github.
here is the link [docker-compose.yaml](https://github.com/apache/airflow/blob/master/docs/apache-airflow/start/docker-compose.yaml) and here is the link to the dockerfile[dockerfile](https://hub.docker.com/layers/apache/airflow/master-python3.8/images/sha256-edbca370f42efd6a211e80cbf00d6a7a50f18886f1c273114486cfdd4bce4a33?context=explore)

I want to use a Dag which should grab data out of my SQL Server database. Actually I get the following error:

> no module named pymssql

After I manually installed it, I get an error like *no module named pyodbc*.
When I want to install this manually I get an gcc error, that it is not possible to install.

Does anyone have any clue about this?

Is there any docker-compose file which is able to handle SQL Server connection for Airflow 2?

Thanks in advance

Comment: `pyodbc` is used to connect to *any* database, not only SQL Server. Obviously, it can be installed. You need either `pymssql` or `pyodbc`, not both. You didn't explain how you tried to install those packages though, so people can only guess. I suspect you just copied a `yaml` file from some blog post and tried to get it to work. Things never work this way.

Comment: The steps you need to install and configure either library are described in [the Microsoft docs](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/python/python-driver-for-sql-server?view=sql-server-ver15) but `Microsoft places its testing efforts and its confidence in pyodbc drive`. The steps for pyodbc are [here](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/python/pyodbc/python-sql-driver-pyodbc?view=sql-server-ver15). You can install pyodbc with `pip install pyodbc` on Windows or `sudo -H pip install pyodbc` on Linux/Mac. This allows you to connect to any DB with an ODBC driver, ie all of them

Comment: To connect to a specific database with ODBC, you need to add its ODBC driver. The SQL Server ODBC drive for Linux is [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/odbc/linux-mac/installing-the-microsoft-odbc-driver-for-sql-server?view=sql-server-ver15)

Comment: thanks for the fast reply. With docker there should not be a dependency with this, thats what I thought. It is more a question why airflow 2 got problem with the connection but worked with the first version. Thank you, I already searched for the pyodbc microsoft documentation.

Comment: On the contrary, with docker you have to explicitly list all dependencies. That's what allows Docker containers to work everywhere - they contain all the dependencies explicitly listed in the docker files. You have to install all the dependencies, or use images that already have the dependencies. This has nothing to do with Airflow, and PyODBC is a popular Python library that has nothing to do with Python. The problem is the docker file. Which you didn't post

Comment: Have you added `RUN pip install pyodbc` in the dockerfile?

Comment: `Is there any docker-compose file which is able to handle SQL Server connection for Airflow 2?` Yes, all of them if you write them correctly. This is a bad question. People can't help you with a dockerfile problem if you don't post the dockerfile or what you tried. A `dockerfile` is text that needs to be modified as needed, not a binary that needs to be used unaltered.

Comment: thank you for your time and explanation.Next time I will check my question one more time before ask them.

Comment: Post your dockerfile. Did you add `RUN pip install pyodbc` ? What error did you get?

Comment: I already posted the docker-compose file. With this file I thought everyone should be able to get the image file as well. Some Minutes ago I edit the question the dockerfile link.I did not run it atm. I will check this.

Comment: You didn't. You posted a link to Docker hub, not *your* dockerfile with what you used to install PyODBC. There's no call to `pip` at all, much less an attempt to install `pyodbc`

Comment: ok, I thought it would be enough to tell that i logged into the container and installed it with pip install pymssql. Thank you for telling me how to improve my way to ask question more detailled here!

Comment: actually I just used the docker-compose file and hoped everything should work to my satisfaction. Maybe a bit naive..

Comment: Dockerfiles contain only what the container's creator wants to include. In [this article](https://medium.com/analytics-and-data/setting-up-airflow-on-azure-connecting-to-ms-sql-server-8c06784a7e2b) the author installs the client and pip packages in the `MSSQL` section of the article using `RUN` and CLI commands. The rest discusses how to set up Azure services and isn't needed in you case. You need to add those CLI commands in the dockerfile

Comment: I have to thank you. I  will check this out.